# What happens if one flags an inappropriate answer that is later edited to something acceptable?

Tags: discussion, flags

Let's just assume that one flags an answer, and that flag, barring any changes to the original post would be deemed helpful.  Now, if the flag is still active and the poster changes their answer to something that is no longer inappropriate, will the flag still be marked as helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether the moderator notices the change. When I see what looks like an earnest flag on something that seems way out of whack, I usually check the edit history. If the flag was on the pre-edited version, I'll mark helpful, with no action.

But we often have a lot of pending flags, and these will occasionally fall through the cracks. Also, in my experience on both ends of flagging, it's fairly rare this happens. (If you find it happening to your flags a significant number of times, that might be worth considering as far as whether you might think of waiting and commenting on those posts, first)

Comment: No, it hasn't been an issue for me at all, I was just wondering what would happen.  I figured that this was probably the case, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: I've had this happen to me before, and so I received declined flags against my name.  This could be made more transparent if the review process indicated that the post was edited since being flagged...  Perhaps even notifying the person(s) who flagged it so they could remove the flag if it no longer applies (thus removing clutter from the flagging queue).